# Phoenix Elixir kafka_ex Connection

Tags: apache-kafka, elixir, phoenix-framework

I got two errors during inital connection:

1. > [error] Could not connect to broker "9fac7e99f3bd":9092 because of
   >   error {:error, :econnrefused}
2. > [error] Fetching consumer_group kafka_ex metadata failed with
   >   error_code :consumer_coordinator_not_available

I used kafka_ex version 0.9.0 and I only have one kafka and one zookeeper.

Pls help what should I do fo phoenix config and kafka config.

Comment: What is `9fac7e99f3bd`? Your hostname? A docker container?

Comment: @cricket_007 a docker container

Comment: See if this article helps https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/